# Vue Owl Carousel Rendering Data Outside the Container

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, owl-carousel

I need help, my vue-owl-carousel library is rendering my vue js data outside the container, but when I input the data manually its working fine, here's my code so far:

Input:

```
<carousel class="mb-2" :dots="false" :nav="false" :responsive="responsiveT1" :items="3">
    <div class="mx-1 item" v-for="(brand,index) in brands" :key="index">
        <img class="brand-image" :src="brand.url" @click="redirect(brand.slug)"/>
    </div>
</carousel>
```

Output:

```
<div id="carousel_s4nwluywy5e" class="owl-carousel owl-theme owl-loaded owl-drag">
   <div class="owl-stage-outer">
      <div class="owl-stage"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="owl-nav disabled">
      <div class="owl-prev">next</div>
      <div class="owl-next">prev</div>
   </div>
   <div class="owl-dots disabled"></div>
   <div class="mx-1 item">
       <img src="storage/sample.jpg" class="brand-image">
   </div>
   <div class="mx-1 item">
       <img src="storage/sample.jpg" class="brand-image">
   </div>
   <div class="mx-1 item">
       <img src="storage/sample.jpg" class="brand-image">
    </div>
</div>
```

Expected Output:

```
<div id="carousel_s4nwluywy5e" class="owl-carousel owl-theme owl-loaded owl-drag">
   <div class="owl-stage-outer">
      <div class="owl-stage">
          <div class="mx-1 item">
              <img src="storage/sample.jpg" class="brand-image">
          </div>
          <div class="mx-1 item">
             <img src="storage/sample.jpg" class="brand-image">
          </div>
          <div class="mx-1 item">
            <img src="storage/sample.jpg" class="brand-image">
          </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="owl-nav disabled">
      <div class="owl-prev">next</div>
      <div class="owl-next">prev</div>
   </div>
   <div class="owl-dots disabled"></div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance folks!

Comment: Just found a solution, just wrap the carousel component inside this:

````<div v-if="brands.length">

</div>
````

Comment: You can answer this in an answer and accept it. Also check out the answer given by Dharman

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to destroy the carrousel before your axios or ajax API call inside the methods like this:

```
$('.yourSelector').trigger('destroy.owl.carousel');
```

and once you get the data result you can initialize owl carousel using the `updated()` vuejs lifeCycle combined with the `$nextTick` hook this way:

```
updated() {
  this.$nextTick(function () {
    $('.yourSelector').owlCarousel({
      loop: false,
      rewind: true,
      margin:10,
      nav:true,
      ...
   )}
  })
}
```